# Adding global P value to logistic regression and cox proportional hazards model - Which tests are used? is it the Wald test?

Tags: global, logistic-regression, categorical-data, p-value, cox-regression

I have been asked to add a global p-value to my categorical variables in my multivariable logistic regression model and in my multivariable cox proportional hazard model.

I have used the function `add_global_p()` when using the function `tbl_regression` (which summarizes my results into a table) but I cannot figure out which tests have been used to calculate the global p-value. Is it the wald test? Do I need to specify the test or does it automatically select the test according to the model you have used?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `coxph()` function from `survival` package to fit your cox proportional hazard model, you can use `summary()` call to get the global p-value. There are three p-values calculated using three different tests (likelihood ratio test, Wald test and score logrank test) offered on the bottom of the output.

> library(survival)
>
> model_fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ covariate_1 + ... + covariate_n, data = your_data)
>
> summary(model_fit)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Add the global p-values](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_global_p.html), the function uses car::Anova().